# Grant access using facebook login if that user is part of a facebook group

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authorization, facebook-login

As far as I know, the Facebook API for retrieving group member information was closed down since 2018.

What I need to do is to let a user login via facebook on my site and only grant access if that person is a member of a facebook group, which I or the website also has a user in that group.

Is this still possible via the facebook API currently? Is there any work around?